# Foreign Key Restraints using Linq is extremely slow

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, foreign-keys

I've got a SQL Server database that I'm trying to build a RESTful API for.
I'm using ADO.Net and Linq to retrieve a single row from a table like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public tTrip getTripById(Guid id)
{
    var _trip = (from trips in db.tTrip
                 where trips.ID == id
                 select trips).FirstOrDefault();
    return _trip;
}
```

When I debug the code the correct object is retrieved. If I keep running however, there will be no response. I'm guessing that's because for every foreign key present in the returned row, ADO does another lookup through the other mapped tables which slows down everything by a lot.

If I only select a single column that doesn't contain any FKCs everything works fine.

Any ideas how I can turn off the FKC lookup for that fetched object?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework

Comment: The connection with the SQL Server works through ADO.Net, but in the code I'm using Linq.
I think the Linq part is fine (because the correct object is found pretty quickly), but the foreign key lookups after are what's giving me trouble.

Comment: Still, are you using LINQ to SQL, or EF? Both have 'Linq you can use'.

Comment: Where does the 'db' variable come from? Can you show the complete controller? Or at least the relevant bits?

Comment: I found the problem - In the ObjectContext class (that's where the db variable comes from btw), I had the ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled variable set to true.
Set it to false and the application returns only the Guid for every entry instead of loading the entry details from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - In the ObjectContext class (that's where the 'db' variable comes from btw), I had the ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled variable set to true.

Set it to false and the application returns only the Guid for every entry instead of loading the entry details from the database.